# Does this Vader quote have more meaning than it first appears?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, quotes

Everyone follow along with the voices in your heads as you read this script segment from the end of Episode VI:

> VADER
>   Luke, help me take this mask off.
>
> LUKE
>   But you'll die.
>
> VADER
>   **Nothing... can stop that now.**

Before the prequels were released, that last line would have been given no extra thought. But now, understanding how Anakin fell to the dark side, it seems like it could be more meaningful than that. His fall was entirely rooted in his inability to accept the inevitability of death, and specifically his frustration that even he was powerless to stop those he loved from dying. Now in his last moments, it looks like he can finally admit the truth that he fought his whole life.

So my question is, do we know if this line is intentionally deep, or am I reading too far into it? From what I understand, Lucas had the full story somewhat figured out by the time Ep VI came around, so it seems possible that it was written that way on purpose.

Comment: Only George Lucas could answer this definitively.  Unless he has, and someone can find the quote, but personally I think that you're reading too much into it.

Comment: @David I thought about that, but then I thought maybe a novel could have some internal monologue about it. Obviously nothing about the prequels, but something about him accepting it.

Comment: I think it was intended to have more than one meaning.  But this question is not a good fit for SE.  There is plenty of places you can debate the intent and hidden meanings SE is not the place for that.

Answer (score 1):

Vader had both been physically injured during his battle with Luke and later electrocuted by the Emperor. Vader's suit was primarily just an iron lung. It's safe to say that the suit wouldn't have done much for the injuries that he sustained (if it was still operating properly), especially without immediate medical attention.

Comment: Sorry, I'm well aware of why he was dying. I'm just saying it seems interesting that he's actually admitting it so bluntly.

Comment: He didn't have much time to waste, so why not?

Comment: @Tesserex - Vader (or Anakin) was not exactly known for NOT being blunt.